# Android: ScrollBar bug in 2.2 for ListView

Tags: android, listview, scrollbar, android-2.2-froyo

The problem appears in Android 2.2. It seems cool because it can auto-hide.But I don't like it quite much because the bar is an indicator for "Whether there is more content not present on the widget". Hiding it maybe neat, but may get the users wrong sometimes. In ListView, I find it a fatal bug at all. When there is more content to show, no scrollbar present, AND when wipe the screen down-wards, no scroolbar appears. Only when use the traceball or Dpad to move focus, there appears the scrollbar. BUT THERE IS WORSE: when you wipe down-wards to move the scrollbar down, nothing happens! The touch feature is almost disabled here.

Can anyone help me here? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is your question...

Comment: The ListView's scroll bar can't be used by direct touch-then-move. Selecting items with Dpad or traceball force the scroll bar appear but still can't move the screen. In one word, the you can't use the listView in touch screen mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe answers there will help you
[Android ListView that does not scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192595/android-listview-that-does-not-scroll)

I had a listview inside of a scrollview. After I'd commented scrollview it was possible to use listview's scrolling.

The weird thing is, that this problem occurs only on Android 2.2.

Comment: Yes. The listView in a scrollView will fail in 2.2. What will you do if you have a long list and some other widget in the screen? Wow, what google did to 2.2?

Answer (score 0):

I am using a listView in android 2.2 and it works just fine . The vertical scrolling happens implicitly without the inclusion of a scroll view . Hope your ListView id is @android:id/list.
And a small correction , to move down the list , you need to wipe the screen UPWARDS not DOWNWARDS ....