# Why using LayoutInflater is not same to xml?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater

I created this layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_weight=".7" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:src="@mipmap/icon" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/delete_button" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/icon"
            android:text="name"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The output is

[image]

When I sure the display is correct, I separate the item to another xml file

mainactivity.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_weight=".7" >
</LinearLayout>
```

item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:src="@mipmap/icon" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/delete_button" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/icon"
        android:text="name"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And then add item in onCreate of mainactivity

```
LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(this);
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null, true);
list.addView(view); //(R.id.list), LinearLayout list
```

Now the output is

[image]

And even I add many view to this linearlayout, still only one view can be added into layout

```
LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(this);
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null, true);
View view2=inflater.inflate(R.layout.other_item, null, true);
list.addView(view); //(R.id.list), LinearLayout list
list.addView(view2);
```

What is correct way to add view to layout?

Comment: I am not sure but check out this link may be you get help [clcik here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8540660/2715073)

Comment: just use: `inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, list)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, list, false);
list.addView(view); //(R.id.list), LinearLayout list
```

Explanation:

The second argument to `inflate()` is the intended parent of the view to be inflated. When you pass `null` as the second argument, the inflated view does not get any `LayoutParams` because `inflate()` doesn't know what the parent eventually will be and thus cannot create the appropriate `LayoutParams` (almost every `ViewGroup` defines its own `LayoutParams` subclass).

When you call `addView()`, the `LinearLayout` checks if the child has `LayoutParams` and whether they are of the appropriate type. If not, it generates some default `LayoutParams` to set on the view being added. Whatever default it gives the child is causing the unexpected behavior.

In short, the solution is to pass `list` instead of `null` when you call `inflate()`.