# ListView contents get cutoff after Adapter update

Tags: android, listview, dynamic

I have a number of vertically stacked panels in my UI. Each panel contains a ListView. Based on user interaction, the number of items in the ListView gets updated.

My problem is that if I increase the number of items being shown in the ListView, the containing panel will not expand to show them. Instead, my ListView just gets cut off with a fade to black. I am programmatically creating each of these stacked panels - this is the body of the creating function:

```
LinearLayout containingPanel = new LinearLayout(TestActivity.this);
containingPanel.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

// create title
TextView titleText = new TextView(TestActivity.this);
titleText.setText("a title");
titleText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
titleText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


// create dynamic list view of costs                
ListView dynamicContentListView = new ListView(TestActivity.this);
dynamicContentListView.setAdapter(new MyDynamicAdapter());
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.weight = 1;
dynamicContentListView.setLayoutParams(params);

// build up GUI

containingPanel.addView(titleText); 

containingPanel.addView(dynamicContentListView);                        
return containingPanel;
```

I thought that setting the weight on the ListView should be enough, but it is not. All GUI updating is working fine - new items are automatically added to data backing the Adapter, and the ListView updates itself properly. But after I add three or four new items, the containingPanel refuses to update itself and the new items get blended out.

Comment: is it possible to scroll  down the listviews to view the cut down portion?

Comment: no, it's not possible (although that may be because all of the containingPanels are themselves inside a scrollview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(You can add a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView` but not without a little work (as they are both Scrollable components - how would the OS know which one you're trying to scroll?). You would need to add `isScrollContainer="false"` on your ListView.)

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_contents"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"/>
```

The entire point of a `ListView` is it has a set height  as dictated by the layout of your page. It only becomes scrollable when it's children's combined height exceed the area required to display it.

It sounds like what you actually want is something more akin to a LinearLayout which is backed by an Adapter, there are several implementations out there on the web or you can create your own.

However, you can hack a ListView into this behaviour by dynamically resizing your `ListView` programatically by setting it's Height to: `listCount * itemHeight`. This would have the effect of consistently expanding your ListView.

You will likely find that as you develop your UI design you will no longer require such a component.

Comment: that's great - that is exactly what I was looking for. Turns out the list I was making was actually scrollable, but since the entire set of containing panels were in a scroll pane, it was confusing.

this answer was also helpful to me [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192595/android-listview-that-does-not-scroll)

Answer (score 3):

try this function. I think, it might help you. The function is used to set `ListView`'s height based on its children.

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null) {
            // pre-condition
            return;
        }

        int totalHeight = 0;
        int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            listItem.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();
    }
```

Comment: works well with the previous answer, but in the end I extended LinearLayout to include a getAdapter() and setAdapter(), and now everything works fine. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your listview is a default size, it might not be able to fit them in the layout. You could try to wrap the listview in a scrollview and then you can scroll through them.

Comment: It looks like the ListView should be scrollable, but it is not. But in any case, I don't want the ListView to be scrollable. I would like the containing panel to expand to the new ListView size.

Comment: Try to create a scroll view dynamically and add the linear layout to it(if its possible)

Comment: that would be possible, but again, i don't want the list view to scroll. i want the containing panel to resize.