# Set list view height without TextView with adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I have a `ListView` which is supposed to become a menu with two drawables and two text views per row.

Activity Code:

```
ArrayList<MenuItem> itemArray = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();
        itemArray.add(new MenuItem("Headertexxt", "subbtexdt"));
        itemArray.add(new MenuItem("asf", "asf"));

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewCM);

        String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.buttonsCM);
        int[] images =  new int[] { R.drawable.btn_car, R.drawable.btn_star, R.drawable.btn_bag};
        listView.setAdapter(new HomeScreenButtonsAdapterSubtext(this, R.layout.row,
                itemArray, images, R.drawable.list_arrow));

        Utils.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listView);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    findViewById(R.id.buttonCreditCompilation).performClick();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    findViewById(R.id.buttonYourCredits).performClick();
                    break;

                }
            }
        });
```

Adapter code:

```
public class HomeScreenButtonsAdapterSubtext extends ArrayAdapter<MenuItem> {

        private Drawable[] drawables;

        private Drawable arrowDrawable;
        private ArrayList<MenuItem> items;

        public HomeScreenButtonsAdapterSubtext(Context context, int resourceId,
                ArrayList<MenuItem> items, int[] images, int arrowImage) {
            super(context, resourceId, items);
            this.items = items;

            Resources resources = context.getResources();
            if (images != null) {
                drawables = new Drawable[images.length];
                int i = 0;
                for (int id : images) {
                    Drawable drawable = resources.getDrawable(id);
                    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                            drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
                    drawables[i++] = drawable;
                }
            }

            arrowDrawable = resources.getDrawable(arrowImage);
            arrowDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, arrowDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                    arrowDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
             View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
             if (v instanceof TextView) {
             Drawable dr = drawables != null ? drawables[position %
             drawables.length] : null;
             ((TextView) v).setCompoundDrawables(dr, null, arrowDrawable, null);
             Utils.setFont((TextView) v);
             }

//          View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            }

            MenuItem station = items.get(position);
            if (station != null) {
                TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.headerText);
                TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.subText);


                if (tt != null) {
                    tt.setText(station.getHeaderText());
                }
                if (bt != null) {
                    bt.setText(station.getSubText());
                }

            }

            return v;
        }
```

The problem I have right now is that I can't set the `listview height` based on the children. I'm trying to do that here: `Utils.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listView);` but getting the error: `arrayadapter requires the resource id to be a textview` at this row. Does anyone know a solution for this?

Can I use some other method for setting the `ListView` height?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but getting the error: arrayadapter requires the resource id to be a
>   textview at this row.

`R.layout.row` is a layout file which it doesn't have just a `TextView`. If you call the super constructor you have used and you also call the `super.getView`(in the `getView` method) method in the adapter, then `ArrayAdapter` will complain as it expects a single widget in the layout file passed to it(a single `TextView`).

I don't understand why you have that piece of code in the `getView` method(with the super call) when you know precisely that the row can't be an instance of `Textview` .

I'm not sure about setting the height of the `ListView` either, if you're trying to show all the rows of the `ListView`, don't do it(as you make the `ListView` basically useless). If you still want to do this, then it's better to lose the `ListView` and build the row layouts manually.

Comment: this answer works, but I got much help from this and got much help from this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11967081/1436948

Answer (score 1):

In fact it does not really make sense to set the height of `ListView` depending on its content.

Because the whole point of a `ListView` is to make its content scrollable (however big it is)...so it is supposed to have a fixed height.