# ScrollView with a ListView doesn't scroll - android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, scroll, android-scrollview

My problem with the following layout is that the layout doesn't scroll. My requirement is that I have to display 2 lists which at times can be big. So i put both the ListViews inside a ScrollView so that i can scroll to the bottom and have a look at both the ListViews. `I don't want the ListView to scroll`. I only want my ScrollView to behave as it should. Any suggestions??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewContactDetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:fillViewport="true">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="22dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/numbersLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="1" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/numbersLayoutList"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="1" >

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/numbersList"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:dividerHeight="2dp" >
                    </ListView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/emailLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|center"
                    android:gravity="top|right"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/emailId"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:gravity="right|center"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="#8d8d8d"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/emailLayoutList"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="1" >

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/emailList"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:dividerHeight="2dp" >
                    </ListView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3193909/1118475

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I spent days trying to figure out how to achieve this and couldn't find any solution. **`You should not put a ListView inside a ScrollView`** was the common saying everywhere I searched. I didn't want to use LinearLayout or ViewGroup because I had already created the whole UI using ListView and it looked awesome to me and everyone else. It worked well except that the page didn't scroll.

Recently I stumbled upon a question here and thought to give this answer a try. It works flawlessly!

Here's the solution:

```
public class Utility {
    public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter(); 
        if (listAdapter == null) {
            // pre-condition
            return;
        }

        int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

Just call `Utility.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(yourListView)` after you have assigned the adapter to your listview and you're done!

A big thanks to `DougW` for coming up with the answer. Here is the original link [How can I put a ListView into a ScrollView without it collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3495908/1117338)

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't put listview in to scrollview, it's not a good idea. If you don't want it to scroll, maybe you shouldn't use listviews. Have you tried with LinearLayouts?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting two listview you can use one listview and you can add both data or inflate both xml file  in the adapter of that listview. This will show both data in one listview and scroll the data with  one scroll bar.

Answer (score 1):

Before calling the below method,

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter(); 
        if (listAdapter == null) {
            // pre-condition
            return;
        }

        int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

You must remove the property 'android:fillViewport="true" from scrollview. If not, scrolling not works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

You removed scroll view from your layout because that is not working correctly for list view..

And also you put the height `"android:layout_height="fill_parent"` for listview so that is occupy full height of parent layout.

so please fix some height manually for both listview.

Answer (score 0):

found the solution just add :

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
```

to the List view :3

```
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/ListViewPrzebiegTrasy"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true">
            </ListView>
```