# Android auto merge two listview in one screen

Tags: android, android-listview

My view look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <!--list 1-->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

 <!--the header-->
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/llIndustries"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/dark_grey_title_bar"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp" >
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/industry_clusters"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>
 </LinearLayout>

  <!--list 2-->
  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvIndustries"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

I use two custom adapter to display two list view (the listview data source completely different each other):

```
private List<MenuInfo> menuData;
private List<MenuInfo> industriesData;

lvMenu = (ListView) layoutRoot.findViewById(R.id.lvMenu);
lvIndustries = (ListView) layoutRoot.findViewById(R.id.lvIndustries);

menuAdapter = new MenuAdapter(getActivity(), menuData);
lvMenu.setAdapter(menuAdapter); 

industriesAdapter = new MenuAdapter(getActivity(), industriesData);     
lvIndustries.setAdapter(industriesAdapter);
```

What I expect is:

```
 <ListView/> <!-- listview 1-->
 <TextView/> <!-- header-->
 <ListView/> <!-- listview 2-->
```

But the problem is two list view auto merged into one `ListView`, and the header `TextView` disappear (If has one `ListView`, the header will be showed).
I have no idea for this issue. Could you please tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: Please brief your question more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below example:
Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/face"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Header"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/background"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

In your class

```
 ListViewAdapter arrayAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, values);

            listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        ListViewAdapter arrayAdapter2 = new ListViewAdapter(this, values2);

            listview2.setAdapter(arrayAdapter2);
```

Add these two lines in onCreate with your listview:

```
Utility.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listview);
        Utility.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listview2);
```

Create a inner class in your Activity:

```
//Test scrollview custom
    public static class Utility {
        public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
            ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter(); 
            if (listAdapter == null) {
                // pre-condition
                return;
            }

            int totalHeight = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
                listItem.measure(0, 0);
                totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
            }

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
            listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    }
```

Code taken from : [listViewNotScrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702650/scrollview-with-a-listview-doesnt-scroll-android)

It would definitely work! :)

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me too. But the second listview always scroll (I don't want both listviews scrollable, instead to root layout should be scrollable). I tried to set `android:scrollbars="none"` for both listview and add scrollview for root layout but doesn't work. Could you recommend any idea?

Comment: You only want first listView to scroll and not second?

Comment: I want both two list view not to scroll. The root layout contain 2 listview should scrollable.

Comment: You shouldn't use ListView inside ScrollView.What you can do is use simply LinearLayout inside ScrollView

Comment: I dont know if these works but you can try them: 1. [scollLIst](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing/3495908#3495908)  2. [anotherLink](http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/12/listview-into-scrollview-in-android.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create Listview with Header. Then Use Section Header Listview.

Refer [this](http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/08/section-header-listview-in-android.html) Example.

Hope it will help you!!

OR

If its fix that Only Two Listview & one Header Between them

Then

1) Take Only one Listview.

2) Use Custom Adapter & Custom Layout for Listview Row.

3) Add Two Extra TextView in Custom Layout

Listing First ListView Data

- (Fixed TextView - Header -Put its Visibility VISIBLE)
- (Extra 1 TextView - Header -Put its Visibility GONE )
- (Extra 2 TextView - Header -Put its Visibility GONE )

Listing Second ListView Data

- (Fixed TextView - Header -Put its Visibility GONE )
- (Extra 1 TextView - Header -Put its Visibility VISIBLE )
- (Extra 2 TextView - Header -Put its Visibility VISIBLE )