# Why views can't be shown after listview?

Tags: android, listview

I'm making a simple custom navigation drawer for my android app and I have a ListView in it that populates with simple cursor adapter. After the listview I have some other views like textview and when the listview gets too much items no views after that show anymore. I tried the nested scroll views with coordinator and scroll view but it seems not just working. also i could use nested scroll view without fillViewport and give my list view a height but that doesn't seem so right so I wanted to see is there any other way to show the views after listview?
This is my navigation drawer layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="start|left"
        android:layout_width="235dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_width="235dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                android:layout_width="235dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:textSize="17sp"
                        android:background="#6C6A6A"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Notes"/>
                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/notes_drawer_list"
                        android:entries="@array/drawer_all_notes_menu"
                        android:divider="@color/black"
                        android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:textSize="17sp"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:background="#6C6A6A"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Tags"/>
                    <! the list view that is populated with cursor adapter!>
                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/tags_drawer_list"
                        android:divider="@color/black"
                        android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:textSize="17sp"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:background="#6C6A6A"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i was searching for the answer for two days and i just seen this question that was asked some time ago and it was just perfectly working for my situation so i thought to send that questions link here.
Here is the answer:

[ScrollView with a ListView doesn't scroll - android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14702650/15220892)